# TypeScript Error with queryFn in RTK Query when using Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux, rtk-query

I'm trying to implement RTK Query in a project that uses Firebase as a backend. I'm facing an issue with TypeScript when defining a mutation using queryFn. Here is my current (relevant) code:

```
export const transactionsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'transactionsApi',
    baseQuery:  fakeBaseQuery(), 
    tagTypes: ['Transactions'],
    endpoints: (builder) => {
        return {
            addTransaction: builder.mutation<void, AddTransactionArgs>({
                // since we are using fakeBaseQuery we use queryFn
                queryFn: async(args) => {
                    // define transaction Ref
                    const transactionCollectionRef = collection(db, 'transactions');
                    try {
                        const docRef = await addDoc(transactionCollectionRef, {
                            ...args, 
                            createdAt: serverTimestamp()
                          });
                    return { data: { docRef, success: true } };
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return { error: err };
                    }

                }
            })
        };
    }
});
```

I'm receiving the following TypeScript error:

> Type '(args: AddTransactionArgs) => Promise<{ data: { docRef: DocumentReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>; success: boolean; }; error?: undefined; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type '(arg: AddTransactionArgs, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: any) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, unknown, {}>>) => MaybePromise<...>'.

I've tried including the additional parameters (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) in queryFn, but I'm still facing issues with the types. How can I resolve this error and correctly define my mutation with queryFn in RTK Query when used with Firebase?

Comment: You've typed the `addTransaction` mutation to have a `void` `ResultType` but are clearly returning some data. See [Typing query and mutation endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-query-and-mutation-endpoints) and [Using a Third-party SDK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#using-a-third-party-sdk) for details. That said, I think the issue may be with how you've typed that `fakeBaseQuery` function return. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: That solved the issue, I just created a type for the result and replaced void for it. Thanks man!